# When to not use PDAs

Tags: anchor, rust, pda, anchor-lang, keypair

I'm building a project that uses PDAs quite extensively. It seems to me that PDAs are very useful for almost every type of application (alternative for hash maps, storing user data etc) and not having to create a new keypair.

When do PDAs not make sense to use? And what would the user interface experience be like? Would the client create a new key pair for the user, who then needs to save the keypair to interact with said new program account in future?

Answer (score 1):

PDAs are certainly useful in the vast majority of situations, but they have a couple of drawbacks:

- you can only allocate up to 10KB per top-level instruction, whereas non-PDA accounts allow you to allocate up to 10MB in a top-level instruction
- PDAs require a program to "sign" for them, so you have to go through a protocol to create the account
- address derivation schemes for PDAs need to be carefully designed to avoid collisions or running out of possible addresses to use. For example, if you derive a PDA based on a user's pubkey, then they can only have one account on your system. That might be beneficial, but it could also cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, PDAs are not only useful to avoid creating new Keypairs, because accounts which are on the curve are PDAs, but accounts which are not on the curve (Keypairs because they have a private key) so your program wouldn't be able to write data to those accounts.

But the question is a bit weird, PDAs make sense to use when you need to store data related to the program, such as particular things for each user for example. Each user will have their PDAs derived with their pubkey address for example.

Comment: by "accounts which are on the curve are PDAs", do you mean off the curve are PDAs?

so PDAs allow a user to store data. I'm assuming one cannot store data on a non PDA account right?

sorry if my question doesn't make sense, a bit of a beginner